# Kern record in SyncTeX file points to tag that does not exist?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

Take a simple document:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Compile with lualatex (although similar behavior is seen with PDFTeX and XeTeX) with synctex enabled.

Then, the synctex file contains:

```
SyncTeX Version:1
Input:1:/tmp/./a.tex
Input:2:/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Input:3:/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
Input:4:/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty

[............]

Output:pdf
Magnification:1000
Unit:1
X Offset:0
Y Offset:0
Content:
!598
{1
[1,8:4736286,4736286:26673152,41484288,0

[............]

g1,7:23865841,9651486
x1,7:24960292,9651486
x1,7:26710758,9651486
g1,7:27001612,9651486
x1,7:27839162,9651486
x1,7:29004392,9651486
g1,7:29295247,9651486
x1,7:30207508,9651486
k231,13363:29295247,9651486:-18350
x1,8:31409438,9651486
g1,7:31409438,9651486
)
(1,7:8799518,10437918:22609920,454820,135004
x1,7:10037493,10437918
x1,7:10916986,10437918
```

According to https://man.archlinux.org/man/synctex.5.en :

- The line `g1,7:29295247,9651486` means that there is a glue, with `1,7` as the link and `29295247,9651486` as the point.

  The point is probably a coordinate in the resulting PDF file. The link `1,7` means the tag is 1, and the line number is 7.

  According to the first section,

  ```
  Input:1:/tmp/./a.tex
  ```

  tag 1 means `/tmp/./a.tex`.
- However, the problem is the following line:

  ```
  k231,13363:29295247,9651486:-18350
  ```

  The format specification is `<kern record> ::= "k" <link> ":" <point> ":" <Width> <end of record>`.

  Once again, `231,13363` is the link, where `231` is the tag and `13363` is the line (number).

  Problem: **nowhere in the synctex file does there exist a `Input:231`**.

Question: **what is going on here**?

Comment: Actually it seems that some time ago the kern get the correct links. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480753/how-does-synctex-work so it's probably just a bug...?